# Receiving an AttributeError all of a sudden

Tags: python, list, random, tkinter, label

I have a block of code which choose a word from a list and displays it on a label and the user has to retype it correctly to move on.

```
import random
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

WORDS = ['Games', 'Development', 'Keyboard', 'Speed', 'Typer', 'Anything',
         'Alpha']
score = 0

def choose_word():
    global word
    entry.focus_set()
    word = random.choice(WORDS)
    label.config(text=str(word.lower()))

def check_entry(event):
    global score
    if entry.get().lower() == word.lower():
        score += 1
        print(score)
    elif entry.get().lower() != word.lower():
        score -= 1
        print(score)
    choose_word()
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
entry = tk.Entry(root)

label.pack()
entry.pack()

choose_word()
root.bind('<Return>', check_entry)
root.mainloop()
```

I've been using this same code throughout ALL versions of my code since I started working on it a few months ago. I haven't altered it one bit and it's worked perfectly up until now. The error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ernxs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ernxs\Downloads\speedtypr\Speedtypr FINAL\speedtyper.pyw", line 685, in choose_word
    label.config(text=str(word.lower()))
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I noticed this error last week as it occurred rarely but now I can't get past the first word without it throwing this error. My code has gone through MAJOR changes throughout the past months but I have left these functions and anything related to them completely untouched and I have no idea why it worked perfectly for 3 months then has now stopped working.

I've tried the above code and it works perfectly but when I run it inside my full program I get the error despite nothing else being related to the functions  I mentioned.

I've tried included even more of my program (which I hope is not too much) but it still won't throw the same error:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk

except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

import time
import random

correct_words = []
WORDS = ['Basic', 'Christmas', 'Summer', 'Sports', 'Winter', 'Negative',
         'Beach', 'Country', 'Christmas', 'Food', 'Games', 'Music', 'Family']

time_score = 0 
word_count = 0
max_words = 12
skips = 0
total_words = 0
words_found = 0

def end_game():
    root.destroy()
def choose_word():
    global word, start_time
    go_btn.pack_forget()
    start_time = time.time()
    entry.focus_set()
    if word_count < max_words:

        word = random.choice(WORDS)

        label.config(text=str(word.lower()))
        time_score_label.config(text="Time: " + str(time_score) + "s")      

    else:
        end_game()

def check_entry(event):
    if entry.get().lower() == word.lower():
        update_right()

    elif entry.get().lower() != word.lower():
        update_wrong()

    if len(entry.get()) < 1:
        update_skip()

    update_time()    
    choose_word()
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)

def update_time():
    global time_score
    time_score += time.time() - start_time
    time_score = round(time_score,2)

def update_skip():
    global skips
    skips += 1
    skip_counter.config(text="Skips: " + str(skips))
    wrong_label.config(text="SKIPPED!", fg='red')
    time_score_label.config(text="Time: " + str(time_score) + "s")

def update_right():
    global word_count, words_found

    word_count += 1
    words_found += 1
    WORDS.remove(word)
    correct_words.append(word)

    time_score_label.config(text="Time: " + str(time_score) + "s")
    word_counter.config(text="Words: " + str(word_count))
    wrong_label.config(text="")

def update_wrong():    
    wrong_label.config(text="WRONG!", fg='red')
    time_score_label.config(text="Time: " + str(time_score) + "s")

def display():
    for i in (label, time_score_label, word_counter, skip_counter, wrong_label,
        entry):
        i.pack()
    choose_word()

root = tk.Tk()
go_btn = tk.Button(root, text="GO!", command=display, width=17)
go_btn.pack()
label = tk.Label(root, font=("Helvetica", 60))
time_score_label = tk.Label(root, text="Time: " + str(time_score) +
                                "s", font=('Helvetica', 14))
word_counter = tk.Label(root, text="Words: " + str(word_count),
                            font =("Helvetica", 14))
skip_counter = tk.Label(root, text="Skips: " + str(skips),
                            font =("Helvetica", 14))
wrong_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font =("Helvetica, 14"))
entry = tk.Entry()

root.bind("<Return>", check_entry)
root.mainloop()
```

This is everything related to this function and I can't reproduce the error. I won't post my full program since it is way too long so is there anything else I can try?

Comment: A guess would be that you re-define the name "word" somewhere else.  Change the name in the function to word_1 or something and see if it helps.

Comment: label.config(text=str(word.lower())) does not use the "word" picked from "WORDS" list, somehow it is confused with "global word", if you rename it, you will not get error.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the above code seems to run correctly, however the error you are receiving tells us that somewhere else, your code (or code you're using from elsewhere) is also declaring a 'global word' and reassigning it to a generator.

**edit:**

*Reading a comment below triggered an additional thought; since 'word' is not declared in check_entry, and check_entry is then bound to a tkinter event, this could possibly manifest the issue without external redeclaration of the "word" variable. I am not familiar with Tkinter's codebase, but depending on how they trigger/store events, there may be a promissory return (generator's yield) call which represents 'word' in that bound state. **You could test this theory by declaring 'word' as global within the check_entry function**, though I still strongly recommend the proposed OOPier solution instead of this shortcut, even if it works*

I would suggest that you refactor to use a class here to avoid using globals to fix the issue. See below, but please note this is NOT a perfect refactor; you should try to isolate the TK Inter work into a separate class as per good practices:

```
    try:
    import tkinter as tk

except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

import time
import random


class MyProgram(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.word = None
        self.start_time = None
        self.correct_words = []
        self.WORDS = ['Basic', 'Christmas', 'Summer', 'Sports', 'Winter', 'Negative',
                 'Beach', 'Country', 'Christmas', 'Food', 'Games', 'Music', 'Family']

        #self.WORDS = ["test"]
        self.time_score = 0
        self.word_count = 0
        self.max_words = len(self.WORDS)
        self.skips = 0
        self.total_words = 0
        self.words_found = 0
        self.setup_tk_components()

    def setup_tk_components(self):
        self.go_btn = tk.Button(root, text="GO!", command=self.display, width=17)
        self.go_btn.pack()
        self.label = tk.Label(root, font=("Helvetica", 60))
        self.time_score_label = tk.Label(root, text="Time: " + str(self.time_score) +
                                        "s", font=('Helvetica', 14))
        self.word_counter = tk.Label(root, text="Words: " + str(self.word_count),
                                    font =("Helvetica", 14))
        self.skip_counter = tk.Label(root, text="Skips: " + str(self.skips),
                                    font =("Helvetica", 14))
        self.wrong_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font =("Helvetica, 14"))
        self.entry = tk.Entry()

    @staticmethod
    def end_game():
        root.destroy()

    def choose_word(self):
        self.go_btn.pack_forget()
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.entry.focus_set()
        if self.word_count < self.max_words:

            self.word = random.choice(self.WORDS)

            self.label.config(text=str(self.word.lower()))
            self.time_score_label.config(text="Time: " + str(self.time_score) + "s")
            self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        else:
            MyProgram.end_game()

    def check_entry(self, event):
        if self.entry.get().lower() == self.word.lower():
            self.update_right()

        elif self.entry.get().lower() != self.word.lower():
            self.update_wrong()

        if len(self.entry.get()) < 1:
            self.update_skip()

        self.update_time()
        self.choose_word()

    def update_time(self):
        self.time_score += time.time() - self.start_time
        self.time_score = round(self.time_score, 2)

    def update_skip(self):
        self.skips += 1
        self.skip_counter.config(text="Skips: " + str(self.skips))
        self.wrong_label.config(text="SKIPPED!", fg='red')
        self.time_score_label.config(text="Time: " + str(self.time_score) + "s")

    def update_right(self):
        self.word_count += 1
        self.words_found += 1
        self.WORDS.remove(self.word)
        self.correct_words.append(self.word)

        self.time_score_label.config(text="Time: " + str(self.time_score) + "s")
        self.word_counter.config(text="Words: " + str(self.word_count))
        self.wrong_label.config(text="")

    def update_wrong(self):
        self.wrong_label.config(text="WRONG!", fg='red')
        self.time_score_label.config(text="Time: " + str(self.time_score) + "s")

    def display(self):
        for i in (self.label, self.time_score_label, self.word_counter, self.skip_counter, self.wrong_label, self.entry):
            i.pack()
        self.choose_word()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    mp = MyProgram()

    root.bind("<Return>", mp.check_entry)
    root.mainloop()
    print mp.correct_words
```

Edit: a simpler example of what is happening where another function changes my string to an int:

```
def asstr():
    global word
    word = "WORD"
def asint():
    global word
    word = 1

asstr()
print word
print word.lower()
asint()
print word
print word.lower()
```

outputs:

```
WORD
word
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: I don't see how `word` could be reassigned between the time `random.choice` assigned a new value, and `test=str(word.lower())`.  I agree that `global` could cause problems, but I have my doubts about this instance.

Comment: the word.lower() which is throwing the error I believe is the one in the check_entry call, which is bound within tkinter, not the one in choose_word. since 'word' is unbound in the check_entry call, it would be holding a generator rather than a word at the time the <Return> bind triggers (I think)

Comment: That doesn't seem consistent with the stated error.  But the intermittent occurrence would be more likely in something bound to `tk` events.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `choose_word` function, with the lines:

```
word = random.choice(WORDS)
label.config(text=str(word.lower()))
```

It appears to work with a list of strings `WORDS`, picking one.  `word.lower()` is a string operation.  I don't know why there's that added `str()` call.

The error indicates that `word` is no longer a string, but a `generator`.  A `generator` is like a list, expect it returns one value at a time, and you can't iterate through it repeatedly.

So you need to focus on `WORDS`.  What is different about it now.  It is also possible that `random.choice` has been changed.

Speaking of this function, why does it use `global word`?  I don't think it is causing a problem, but it doesn't look like good programming practice.

Comment: You've steered me in the right direction, I imported the list from a text file in the original but here I used a list. I removed `.lower()` and saw that somehow the data was being read incorrectly into 'WORDS'. I'll try looking there for anything.